# From HTTPResponse to str in Python 3.6

Tags: python, json, api, vimeo

From a POST request to Vimeo API I get a JSON object encoded as HTTPResponse.

```
r = http.request('POST', 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client?grant_type=client_credentials', headers={'Authorization': 'basic XXX'})
```

I do not find a way to convert the HTTPResponse to a str or Json object. In stackoverflow I found and tried the following options:

```
json.loads(r.decode('utf-8'))

json.loads(r.readall().decode('utf-8'))

str(r, 'utf-8')
```

but none of them worked.

Please can you help?

Thanks

Comment: is there not an `r.text` or `r.body` attribute? what's the output of `dir(r)`

Comment: Hi @RSHAP no r.text or r.body attributes.
the Output of dir(r) is

['CONTENT_DECODERS', 'REDIRECT_STATUSES', '__abstractmethods__',  '__class__',
 '__del__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__enter__',
 '__eq__',
 '__exit__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__next__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 [...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with requests module

```
import requests
import json 

r=requests.post('https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client?grant_type=client_credentials', varData,  headers={'Authorization': 'basic XXX'})
response = json.loads(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse) (emphasis mine):

> `class http.client.HTTPResponse(sock, debuglevel=0, method=None, url=None)`
>
> Class whose instances are returned upon successful connection. **Not instantiated directly by user.**

And also:

> See also The Requests package is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface.

So you're probably better off using [*requests*](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) directly.

After having made your request, just use `json.loads(r.text)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use http.client module. Example:

```
import http.client
import json
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client?grant_type=client_credentials')
headers = {'Authorization': 'basic XXX'}
params = varData
conn.request('POST', '', params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
content = bytes.decode(response.read(), 'utf-8') #return string value
res_map = json.loads(content) #if content is json string
```

For more information, refer this: [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html)